# NSKeyedArchiver doesn't want to encode patterned color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In a project that I am working on, I am having users select a color that will be used as the background for a certain view. They have the option of selecting any of the main colors (ex "redColor"/"blueColor") or creating a color with a custom RGB value. When they select a color, it stores it into an array of "previously used colors" so that they can easily select it again later if they want to reuse it.

Right now everything is working perfectly and I am storing the colors into NSUserDefaults using:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:colorArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"colors"];
```

This works perfectly, however whenever I store a color with a pattern (ex the underPageBackgroundColor), I get the warning:

```
we're encoding a color that has a pattern selector (underPageBackgroundColor) but not a system color name - that shouldn't happen
```

It doesn't stop it from working and it still stores the color and I can retrieve it later. Should I worry about this error and store patterned colors as strings instead or should I ignore it as it doesn't seem to be causing any failures?

Also, does anyone know the reason for this warning? It doesn't seem like it is caused by anything not working as expected.

Comment: seems like a warning that shouldn't be in there. if you want to be safe, why not save your pattern image instead? try to restore the color first, if there's no color, restore a color from your saved pattern image instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing something similar to that, but I'm still wondering what that error is there for.